# Combing addthis scripts

Tags: jquery, addthis

I'm looking to combine the script for shortening with Bit.ly

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = {
     // ... other options
     url_transforms : {
          shorten: {
               twitter: 'bitly'
          }
     }, 
     shorteners : {
          bitly : {} 
     }
}
</script>
```

and the one for changing the Text Shared to Twitter

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = addthis_share || {}
addthis_share = {
    passthrough : {
        twitter: {
            via: "TWITTER USERNAME"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm quite new to scripts and have tried a variations and neither seem to make it work.

Also would anyone know how to link an image into the Twitter share, is it just a case of including the {tag_image} (I'm using Adobe Business Catalyst).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = addthis_share || {}
addthis_share = {
    passthrough : {
        twitter: {
            via: "TWITTER USERNAME",
            text: "TEXT"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am AddThis support agent Elsa. You can combine the scripts as shown below:

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
var addthis_share = addthis_share || {}
addthis_share = {
passthrough : {
twitter: {
text: "text",
via: "Username"
}
},
url_transforms : {
shorten: {
twitter: 'bitly'
}
},
shorteners : {
bitly : {} 
} 
}
</script>`
```

Unfortunately at this moment, we don't support sharing images to twitter.Anyway I will pass your feedback to our product team.

Thanks,
Elsa.